# PHP print_r(apache_get_modules()) gets me 500 error - can't find out why

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, redirect

I've been stuck with setting wordpress multisite for hours and found out I had probably issues with .htaccess configuration... though I followed the instructions [from a manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), I kept getting 500 error when accessing the sites administration...

I googled for hours how to modify the wp-config and .htaccess, nothing worked... so I tried to find out if the mod_rewrite is even active...

```
<?php print_r(apache_get_modules()); ?>
```

But this gives me HTTP 500 error... what could be the problem? There is possibly something wrong with the server settings, but what should I look for?

(I deleted the .htaccess and everything from a root directory except the php file with this line, so wrong .htaccess configuration is surely not causing this issue...)

Thanks for a help! :)

Comment: It will only work if your webserver is apache, for nginx, cli etc doesn't work

Comment: oooh... thanks, I haven't even noticed, the host server uses nginx... that explains everything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apache_get_modules() will only work if php is installed under apache.
If you want to list the extensions you can use:

```
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
```

This will work under CLI too, it will print something like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Core
[1] => date
[2] => libxml
[3] => openssl
[4] => pcre
[5] => zlib
[6] => filter
[7] => hash
[8] => pcntl
....
```